# Customize font d3 chart axis labels

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I am using `d3 bar chart` in my application. I would like to change the `font-family` and `font-size` of the `x'axis` lables displayed.

I tried

```
d3.selectAll('.tick > text').style("font-size",'10px')
```

but didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating the labels with the regular D3 axis component?  Just use CSS on the label classes to change their appearance.

Comment: I tried to add 'font-size:100px;' to the css part of the label using firebug, but it didn't change.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please?